# How do I create custom terminal commands in VS Code and assign key bindings to these commands?

Tags: makefile, visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

Please don't flag as duplicate without reading. Seriously not able to find this information anywhere.

I work on projects that make use of "Make". Right now I have to type every make command in the integrated terminal like "make all", "make clean" etc. I'd like to have some keyboard shortcuts that do the work, similar to how default build tasks have one.

I tried command runner extensions but they too have very vague info on how to make these custom commands. Been fiddling around with settings and keybindings json file for few days now. I'm not a web developer so don't know much about working with json files to begin with and configure stuff observing the default templates.

All I find is the default template of

```
{
     key : " ",
    command : " "
}
```

Tried fiddling with this on keybindings.json file but my command is not found.

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the command `workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence` you can send text to the terminal

An example [key binding](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings)

```json
{
  "key": "ctrl+f5",  // or any other combo
  "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
  "args": { "text": "make all\u000D" }
}
```

Be sure the terminal is at a directory where the command works, or add a `cd` command in front, you can [use variables](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_send-text-via-a-keybinding) (credit to *Mark* for the correction).

If you define multiple tasks to do the stuff you can execute the task with a keybinding

```json
{
  "key": "shift+f5",  // or any other combo
  "command": "workbench.action.tasks.runTask",
  "args": "Name_of_task"
}
```

In the task you can use variables.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. Both the solutions worked. I preferred the one with tasks. Just a quick question - the key binding would work globally as long as I have the task in tasks.json file with that particular label right?

Comment: @Luffy Yes, I don't know if it will work correct if you have a Multi Root workspace

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "you can't use variables" with a `sendSequence` command?  You can, all these: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference

Comment: @Mark Do you mean you can use variables in key bindings in `keybindings.json`, there is no mentioning of this on the key binding page and on the variable page

Comment: @rioV8 See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_send-text-via-a-keybinding (not anywhere in the keybindings, only for `sendSequence` commands).

Comment: @Mark Thanks, that is one of the few doc pages I haven't read yet.